# How do I load text on selection of radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Radio button input which says No and Yes. How do  I load "Hello World" when I select no, and "Hello World 1" when I select yes.

By default, both the hello world and hello world 1 should be disabled. Any help?

Regards,
Bill

```html
<span>No</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input type="radio" name="damage">
</span>

<span class="">Yes</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input type="radio" name="damage">
</span>

<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Hello World 1</p>
```

Comment: `<style>    p{display:none}

    [type="radio"][value="0"]:checked ~ p:first-of-type{
    display:block;
    }
    [type="radio"][value="1"]:checked ~ p:last-of-type{
    display:block;
    }
</style>
    <span>No</span>
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="damage">

    <span class="">Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="damage">

    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World 1</p>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan that won't work, also it's unreadable as a comment. The `<input>` elements are inside those `<span>` containers.

Comment: @Pointy :  yes I know..... just a simple solution if he is looking something simple..

Comment: add different values to both inputs, then bind change event handler and toggle style of elements(or better to toggle a class)

Comment: @PranavCBalan anyway it was a nice approach I wouldn't think of. Also I didn't knew ~ operator. Why don't you put it as an answer so we can upvote it ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira : thanks mate, .... it doesn't fully answer the question, its just an alternate way with using CSS only :)

Comment: Thanks for this approach! Out of the box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to give each radio a data attribute and class. That way you can simplify the code and even plan ahead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $(document).on("change",".data-radio",function(){
        $(".data-content").hide();
        $($(this).data("content")).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.data-content{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>No</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input type="radio" class="data-radio" data-content=".no-damage" name="damage">
</span>

<span class="">Yes</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input type="radio" class="data-radio" data-content=".damaged" name="damage">
</span>

<p class="data-content no-damage">No Damage!</p>
<p class="data-content damaged">Damaged!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be easier to understand.

Here a single `<p></p>` element is created and a specific `id="output-text"` is given to it.

add `onclick` attribute to each radio button and in the listener function (in this code `clicked()` function) pass the data you want to so. And rest of work is done by `javascript`.

See the following code:

```js
function clicked(val) {
  document.getElementById("output-text").textContent = val;
}
```

```html
<span>No</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input onclick="clicked('Hello World')" type="radio" name="damage">
</span>

<span class="">Yes</span>
<span class="float-right mr-3">
<input onclick="clicked('Hello World 1')" type="radio" name="damage">
</span>

<p id="output-text"></p>
```

Hope, this helps. Thanks.